# Socket.io disconnects after certain time interval

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, socket.io

We have created a real time chat application, with a socket.io, nodejs & mongodb. It is working fine on to a local & modulus server, but not working as expected on AWS.

Socket gets disconnected randomly with a ping timeout after around 60 sec. I also set "Heart Timeout" & "Heart Interval" but still it gets disconnected.

Here is the attached config file for node,

```
    var config = {
    local : {
        mode        : "LOCAL",
        port        : 8080,
        db_path     : "mongodb://localhost/local_db",
        site_loc    : "http://dummy.local/",
        api_loc     : "http://dummy.dummy.com/"
    },
    dev : {
        mode        : "DEV",
        port        : 8080,
        db_path     : "mongodb://dbath:27017/dev_db",
        site_loc    : 'http://dummy.dummy.com/',
        api_loc     : 'http://dummy.dummy.com/'
    },
    stage : {
        mode        : "STAGE",
        port        : 3000,
        db_path     : "mongodb://localhost:27017/stage_db",
        site_loc    : 'http://dummy.dummy.com/',
        api_loc     : 'http://dummy.dummy.com/'
    },
    production : {
        mode        : "PROD",
        port        : 443,
        db_path     : "mongodb://localhost:27017/live_db",
        site_loc    : 'https://dummy.com/',
        api_loc     : 'https://dummy.dummy.com/'
    }
}

    module.exports = function(mode) {
        return config[mode || process.argv[2]] || config.local;
    }
```

Comment: Are you using a load balancer?

Comment: No, I have not added load balancer yet.

Comment: Are you using nginex? Also can you paste your socket.io config file in question

Comment: no, aws with ubuntu 14.04, t2 micro. There is no config file for socket, just using a port 3000 for node program

Comment: Can you paste socket.io config file?

Comment: Hello please help!!!!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122123/discussion-between-error2007s-and-jitendra-pawar).

Comment: paste socket.io config file in question

Comment: If everything works fine in one configuration, but the connections get timed out in another configuration, then you apparently have some part of your network infrastructure that is not allowing long lived connections.  There's not much we can do here to solve that for you without knowing a lot about your AWS network configuration.

Comment: Define 'disconnects', 'gets disconnected', etc., and make up your mind as to which it is.

Comment: There is "disconnect" event in socket.io, which will get called from client side , when client closes the connection. But in this case it get called after around 60 sec after connection established. The same code is working fine on local as well as on modulus server, will it be a network configuration problem on AWS? as @jfriend00 suggested.

Comment: I am still facing this issue, socket disconnects with a ping timeout. Anyone has idea why it is happening...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue, by just adding a port number besides link like,

```
http://www.chat.com:3000/
```

by d way thanks everyone...